# How to get certain value from cookie string with PHP or JS?

Tags: javascript, php, string, cookies

A plugin I use stores multiple values in one string.

var_dump looks like this:

```
{\"strict\":\"0\",\"thirdparty\":\"1\",\"advanced\":\"0\"}
```

I need to check if, for example, "advanced" is true or not.

Doing it in php would be great, JS would also be good.

Comment: `var_dump()` outputs the backslashes ?

Comment: try `$array = json_decode($json, true);` (once you get rid of the escape backslashes)

Comment: Yes, that's the full output. I got rid of the backslashes with stripslashes() 
Now I get this using
`$cookie_exampleData_decoded = json_decode($cookie_exampleData, true);`

var_dump()
`array(3) { ["strict"]=> string(1) "0" ["thirdparty"]=> string(1) "1" ["advanced"]=> string(1) "0" }`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $jsIn = '{\"strict\":\"0\",\"thirdparty\":\"1\",\"advanced\":\"0\"} ';
    $jsOut = json_decode(stripslashes($jsIn));
```

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but an explanation would help other readers. For more info read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: While your code may correct as answer But Elaborating what your code does, It can improve the quality of your answer. Checkout the Article : [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $input = '{\"strict\":\"0\",\"thirdparty\":\"1\",\"advanced\":\"0\"}';
    $input = str_replace('\', '', $input);
    $input = json_decode($input, true);
    $advanced = empty($input['advanced']);
```

If your string contains antislashes, you must remove it. Here with `PHP#str_replace` after that you decode the json string to have an association array and finally test `$input['advanced']` with `PHP#empty` that returns `false`  for false, 0, null, or '0' value otherwise true.

Comment: Your answer may be correct, but an explanation would help other readers. For more info read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved and works as intended.
So, first we get rid of the backslashes in the string that's the value of this cookie with **stripslashes()**, in wordpress use **wp_unslash()**. After **json_decode()**  we have access to (in this case) three items ( **strict, thirdparty, advanced** ) which can have a value of **0** or **1**. 
Now, in the **var_dump()** each item contains **string(1)** before the actual value.

```
string(1) "1" 
string(1) "0"
```

The IF statement nevertheless works as intended.

```
$input = json_decode( stripslashes( $_COOKIE['some-cookie'] ), true );
$thirdparty = $input['thirdparty'];
$advanced = $input ['advanced'];

var_dump( $thirdparty );
echo "<br>";
var_dump( $advanced );
echo "<br>";

if ($thirdparty > 0) {
    echo "allowed";
} else {
    echo "not allowed";
}

echo "<br>";

if ($advanced > 0) {
    echo "allowed";
} else {
    echo "not allowed";
}
```

Many thanks to all ...